# Is there any equivalent command for odmget(AIX) in Linux?

Tags: linux, command, aix

I have to replace this line in Linux as [`odmget` is an AIX command](http://aix4admin.blogspot.se/2013/02/aix-odm-commands.html) and is invalid in Linux.

```
C_RAWNODE=`odmget -q"attribute = node_number" CuAt|grep value|sed "s/\"//g"| \
```

Comment: What does `odmget` do? There's nothing on it on http://bhami.com/rosetta.html

Comment: If you were to run this on your AIX system what output would this line produce? (Please [edit] your question to include this information.)

Comment: The ODM is a central config database on AIX, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/odm.htm for those asking.

Answer (score 3):

Linux doesn't have an equivalent of the ODM, and so there's no equivalent command.

The configuration of Linux is spread throughout the filesystem and kernel.

On the assumption that node_number is related to clustering, you'll need to look at commands / files related to which ever clustering product you're using.

In short, it's not the command you're looking to replace, you need to alter the whole approach to getting that information on Linux.